# Understanding the C function call prolog with __cdecl on windows

Tags: c, windows, assembly

Compiling this simple function with MSVC2008, in Debug mode:

```
int __cdecl sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

I get the following disassembly listing:

```
int __cdecl sum(int a, int b)
{
004113B0  push        ebp  
004113B1  mov         ebp,esp 
004113B3  sub         esp,0C0h 
004113B9  push        ebx  
004113BA  push        esi  
004113BB  push        edi  
004113BC  lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h] 
004113C2  mov         ecx,30h 
004113C7  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh 
004113CC  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi] 
    return a + b;
004113CE  mov         eax,dword ptr [a] 
004113D1  add         eax,dword ptr [b] 
}
004113D4  pop         edi  
004113D5  pop         esi  
004113D6  pop         ebx  
004113D7  mov         esp,ebp 
004113D9  pop         ebp  
004113DA  ret
```

There are some parts of the prolog I don't understand:

```
004113BC  lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h] 
004113C2  mov         ecx,30h 
004113C7  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh 
004113CC  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]
```

Why is this required?

---

**EDIT:**

After removing the `/RTC` compiler option, as was suggested, most of this code indeed went away. What remained is:

```
int __cdecl sum(int a, int b)
{
00411270  push        ebp  
00411271  mov         ebp,esp 
00411273  sub         esp,40h 
00411276  push        ebx  
00411277  push        esi  
00411278  push        edi  
    return a + b;
00411279  mov         eax,dword ptr [a] 
0041127C  add         eax,dword ptr [b] 
}
```

Now, why is the: `sub esp, 40h` needed? It's as if place is being allocated for local variables, though there aren't any. Why is the compiler doing this? Is there another flag involved?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code is emitted due to the [/RTC compile option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz.aspx).  It initializes all local variables in your function to a bit pattern that is highly likely to generate an access violation or to cause unusual output values.  That helps you find out when you forgot to initialize a variable.

---

The extra space in the stack frame you see allocated is there to support the Edit + Continue feature.  This space will be used when you edit the function while debugging and add more local variables.  Change the /ZI option to /Zi to disable it.

Comment: That sounds like an explanation - but the function has no local variables!

Answer (score 3):

and in any case of buffer overflow (if you would overwrite local variables) you will end up in a field of "int 3" opcodes:

```
int 3 ; 0xCC
int 3 ; 0xCC
int 3 ; 0xCC
int 3 ; 0xCC
int 3 ; 0xCC
int 3 ; 0xCC
...
```

that can be catched by the debugger, so you can fix your code

Comment: INT 3 is the debugger trap, but it must be executed by the CPU to really enter it, doesn't it? If I just trample over it without executing it doesn't matter that it's INT 3 - or am I misunderstanding this?